# Any shortcut in WebStorm to surround a block of code with an IIFE

Tags: webstorm

That is, if I have a function like:

```
angular.module('sessionController',[]);
```

and I want to change it to

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

     angular.module('sessionController',[]);

}());
```

I was thinking there would be a "code/surround with" type option

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can create the corresponding Live Template (Settings/Live Templates) like the following:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

     $SELECTION$

}());
```

Make sure to set the context (Applicable In...) to 'JavaScript'.

Template can be applied using `Code/Surround with live template (Ctrl+Alt+J)`